# Activity kill after some time when i keep my Activity in background

Tags: android

I am stuck in a complex problem where my activity kill if i keep it in back ground for some times using method moveTaskToBack(true). when i again restart my application then activity's onCreate() method is called.

my code is

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {               

            moveTaskToBack(true);               
            return true;
        }       
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This is expected behavior.  If you would like something to continue to run in the background, you should be using a service rather than just an activity.  However, even then, continued operation cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: activity in background may be killed to reclaim memory based on priority